# MYSQL: Select from all tables in a DB

Tags: mysql

So I have a DB called files and it contains 3 tables (IMG,FLASH,PDF)... how would I run a query on them all and and return everything inside them as a single array?

Comment: Why this way? Why not one table with 'fileType' field?

Comment: Because i store different data dependent on each file, such as PDF has page number, mode .etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the same field in your tables, you can **[UNION](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html)** the results:

```
SELECT content
FROM IMG
UNION ALL
SELECT content
FROM FLASH
UNION ALL
SELECT content
FROM PDF
```

Comment: Use union all if you don't want to remove duplicates. Moreover it runs faster than union.

Comment: True, and I don't think there can be duplicate between a flash and a pdf!

Answer (score 0):

You may be interested by the MySQL [MERGE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/merge-storage-engine.html) storage engine if your 3 tables have identical structures. If not just use [UNION](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html) and use aliases if your columns don't have the same names.

```
SELECT commonColumn1, commonColumn2
FROM IMG
UNION ALL
SELECT commonColumn1, commonColumn2
FROM FLASH
UNION ALL
SELECT commonColumn1, notSoCommonColumn2 AS commonColumn2
FROM PDF
```

Answer (score 0):

do they all have exactly the same column set?

if so you could do a UNION

if not, then you will need to issue 3 queries...

Comment: They do not have identical structure but they share some columns.